# Properties setting via Servlet

Tags: java, file, servlets, properties

I want to set data from `configures.properties` via servlet. `configures.properties` is locating in `WEB-INF/classes`. This is how I'm getting data:

```
public static String getDbPassword() {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try {
            // load a properties file
            InputStream in = Configures.class.getResourceAsStream(INPUT_FILE);
            prop.load(in);

            // get the property value
            return prop.getProperty("dbPassword");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But how to set? This is how I did:

```
public static void setDbPassword(String str) {
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            try {
                //load a properties file
                InputStream in = Configures.class.getResourceAsStream(INPUT_FILE);
                prop.load(in);
                prop.setProperty("dbPassword", str);
                prop.store(new FileOutputStream(INPUT_FILE), null);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

But I'm catching `java.io.FileNotFoundException` after this. I think it happens after `prop.store(new FileOutputStream(INPUT_FILE), null);`. How should I modify `OutputStream`?

**UPD:**
This is how `INPUT_FILE` looks:

```
private static final String INPUT_FILE = "/config.properties";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `INPUT_FILE` is a resource path which `getResourceAsStream` will resolve relative to the classpath, but you're then trying to pass the same string to the `FileOutputStream` constructor which will try and treat it as an absolute path relative to the root of the filesystem. These are two different locations.

You could use `ServletContext.getRealPath("WEB-INF/classes" + INPUT_FILE)` to get the path you need for the `FileOutputStream`.

But the higher level issue here is that you shouldn't assume that your web application will have write access to its `WEB-INF`, or even that the directory exists on disk at all (e.g. if the app is running directly from a WAR rather than a directory unpacked on disk). If you want to store configuration data that can change then it should go in a file at a known location *outside* the web app (the location of this file could be an init parameter) where you know you will have read and write permission. This also stops your changes being overwritten when you deploy a new version of the app.

Answer (score 1):

```
URL url = Configures.class.getResource(INPUT_FILE);
File file = new File(url.toURI());
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

...

prop.store(outputStream, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a FileWriter instead:

```
Writer writer = new FileWriter(INPUT_FILE);
...
prop.store(writer, null);
```

Comment: No, not working. No exceptions, but nothing changes in properties.

Comment: Are you deploying with Eclipse and Tomcat?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following:

While reading the file

```
URL url = classLoader.getResource(INPUT_FILE);
InputStream in = url.openStream();
```

While writing :

```
new FileOutputStream(url.toURI().getPath())
```

Comment: I think, I can't get my file using URL, because it's locating in WEB-INF

Answer (score 1):

Any files in your webapp should be considered read only. If you want mutable data you should use a database or some other data store.

J2EE advises against manipulating local files as it raises issues of clustering, transactions and security among other things.